# GWT: DockLayout Panel not showing

Tags: uibinder, gwt2, docklayoutpanel

Expected output is the same as in the preview, with labels that indicate the specified blocks.

I run this in standard mode and I am using GWT 2.1.1

Below is the **expected output:**

[image: Design in GWT Designer UIBINDER]
[image: Review of output]

**Actual output:**

[image: Output]

```
<html><head>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the    -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into               -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration  -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype may lead to some -->
<!-- differences in layout.                        -->



    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">

    <!--                                                               -->
    <!-- Consider inlining CSS to reduce the number of requested files -->
    <!--                                                               -->
    <link href="DucWMP.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- Any title is fine                         -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>

    <!--                                           -->
    <!-- This script loads your compiled module.   -->
    <!-- If you add any GWT meta tags, they must   -->
    <!-- be added before this line.                -->
    <!--                                           -->
    <script src="ducwmp/ducwmp.nocache.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script><script defer="defer">ducwmp.onInjectionDone('ducwmp')</script>
  <!--                                           -->
  <!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      -->
  <!-- you can leave the body empty if you want  -->
  <!-- to create a completely dynamic UI.        -->
  <!--                                           -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8888/ducwmp/gwt/standard/standard.css"><style>.GC3DVSKBA{background-color:ivory;}</style></head><body>

    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe style="position: absolute; width: 0pt; height: 0pt; border: 0pt none;" tabindex="-1" id="__gwt_historyFrame" src="javascript:''"></iframe>

    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      &lt;div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif"&gt;
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      &lt;/div&gt;
    </noscript>

  <iframe src="javascript:''" id="ducwmp" style="position: absolute; width: 0pt; height: 0pt; border: medium none;" tabindex="-1"></iframe><div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20cm; width: 10cm; height: 10cm;">&nbsp;</div><div style="position: relative;" class="GC3DVSKBA"><div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex;">&nbsp;</div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0em; top: 0em; right: 0em; height: 4em;"><div class="gwt-Label" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">Header + Navigation</div></div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0em; right: 0em; bottom: 0em; height: 2em;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;"><div class="gwt-Label">Group control</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0em; top: 4em; right: 0em; bottom: 2em;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;" class="gwt-SplitLayoutPanel"><div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex;">&nbsp;</div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 128px;"><div class="gwt-Label" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">Right Sidebar</div></div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; right: 128px; bottom: 0px; width: 8px;"><div style="width: 8px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;" class="gwt-SplitLayoutPanel-HDragger"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 136px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="overflow: auto; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"><div style="position: relative;"><div class="gwt-Label">Component Box</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML structure that firebug shows or can you link to a page that contains the compiled output?

Comment: I've added the HTML Output of the file. Should i export it to war and upload? Thank you

Comment: Try adding a `height="100%"` attribute to your html and body tags.

Comment: Perfect. I forgot that the height of parent div is 0. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java code make sure you do

```
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(appWidget);
```

Instead of

```
RootPanel.get().add(appWidget);
```